# yii php unit test Yii::app->user->id error

Tags: yii, phpunit

I m testing a class that saves a model. This model has a behavior where it saves the user of the record which I m going to insert, with this method

```
 public function beforeSave($event) {                       
        if (($this->getOwner()->getTableSchema()->getColumn($this->campoUsuarioCreacion)!==null)) 
            $this->getOwner()->{$this->campoUsuarioCreacion} = Yii::app()->user->id;

        if ($this->getOwner()->getTableSchema()->getColumn($this->campoUsuarioModificacion)!==null) 
            $this->getOwner()->{$this->campoUsuarioModificacion} = Yii::app()->user->id;

       return parent::beforeSave();
    }
```

But when I m testing, there is a problem with Yii::app()->user->id. I think that the problem is that no user is logged in. So, How can I solve the problem, without copying again the class with a harcoded user id? Is there a way to set the app user id?

Answer (score 0):

Without broaching the issue of whether or not the user is logged in or Yii::app()->user->id is defined, you need to add this to the bottom of your function:

```
return parent::beforeSave();
```

eg:

```
public function beforeSave($event) {                       
    if (($this->getOwner()->getTableSchema()->getColumn($this->campoUsuarioCreacion)!==null)) 
        $this->getOwner()->{$this->campoUsuarioCreacion} = Yii::app()->user->id;

    if ($this->getOwner()->getTableSchema()->getColumn($this->campoUsuarioModificacion)!==null) 
        $this->getOwner()->{$this->campoUsuarioModificacion} = Yii::app()->user->id;

    return parent::beforeSave();
}
```

Comment: @jbg. can you explain what the code does. I'll to lazy today to figure this out. ;)